# Moving user profile disks in a 2012 R2 RDS environment

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, migration, vhd, windows-server-2012

I have a situation whereby I have deployed a 2012 R2 RDS environment utilizing user profile disks.

Everything has been good so far, except I made a mistake and stored the UPD's on the DC, so I'm seeing intermittent AD issues due to the NIC on the DC being throttled to high hell and back.

I have deployed a new VM specifically for the purpose of holding the UPD's, however I don't know (and cant seem to find) a straight answer to whether or not I can just move these puppies and get away with it.

I assumed the process would be copy files from the source location to the destination, share the new location, then edit the collection settings in RDS changing the 'location' value under 'User Profile Disks'.

I have read articles which suggested people have seen permissions errors and such like with UPD's which got me a bit itchy, as this is a production environment.

Any suggestions/advice appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

The UPD naming scheme is based on the SID, so as long as the AD stays the same, you shouldn't have issues with copying the UPD files to a new share. Make sure the servers in the collection have full control permissions for the new share. This said, it would be best to test before putting it into production.

Comment: One thing concerning me is that there are permissions on the current share for the session host servers that I cannot replicate. I would hope that applying the change in location would automatically do it, but I can't assume that :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can copy them to a new server, but it is important that the security attributes be preserved. Use robocopy with the `/sec` option to copy them.